# Highlight a part of string using Apache POI

Tags: java, regex, string, apache, ms-word

I want to highlight the patterns in the string that matches a portion of the string. I have identified the pattern in the string and stored them in the array. Now I want them to be highlight in the text in word document to show that these are the pattern that matches the portion of the string.

I have written my string in the word document using Apache POI and I have created word 2007 document.

But I do not know that how can I highlight the patterns in the string in word document.

I have used database at back end in which I placed my patterns and then used those presorted pattern in an array to see that whether or not they occur in my string.

This is my code.

```
   for(int j=0;j<numRows;j++)
        {

   Pattern p = Pattern.compile( strArray[j] );
   m=p.matcher(str);
   while(m.find())//finding pattern in the sequence

   {
    patArray[inpat]=m.group();// stored match pattern in another array
    inpat++;
    System.out.println(m.group());

}
    }
```

Comment: Can you post some code? Such as identifying and storing the string? Thanks

Comment: Duplicate one :- Please find stcakoverflow answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35419619/how-can-i-set-background-colour-of-a-run-a-word-in-line-or-a-paragraph-in-a-do